# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I get an error like the title.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/2.py", line 40, in <module>
reviews.append(reviews_info(div))
  File "C:/2.py", line 21, in reviews_info
    review_text = div.find("div", "review-content").div.text 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'
```

I guess I've probably entered the wrong element.

I did not write the code from scratch. I have applied to the code that was previously crawling other sites.

How can I change the element and turn it??
I think I wrote well. But there is an error.

ps I'm afraid there will be a comment to use api. But this is the way to use it because it is limited.

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote

import os
import xlwt

import re  
import time
import random
import re, requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

# CMD chcp 65001


def reviews_info(div):
    review_text = div.find("div", "review-content").div.text 
    review_stars = div.find("div", "i-stars i-stars--regular-1 rating-large").a.text
    return {
        "review_text" : review_text,
        "review_stars" : review_stars,
    }

base_url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/founding-farmers-d-c-washington-2?start="
reviews = []
NUM_PAGES = 36

for page_num in range(1, NUM_PAGES + 20):
    print("souping page", page_num, ",", len(reviews), "data")
    url = base_url + str(page_num)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml') 

    for div in soup('div', 'review-content'):
        reviews.append(reviews_info(div))
    sleep(5)#############################################
    #  Save dict data
keys = reviews[0].keys()
with open('testtest.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(reviews)
```

Comment: The way you have described about your scraper and to-do list is completely vague. It would be better if you specify the fields you would like to parse from the provided link in your scraper.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you're already passing to `reviews_info` the div that has a class attribute of 'review-content'. So you're probably better off removing the `.find("div", "review-content")` part. That might be a cause for the error.

Apparently, you need the review date and stars.

Instead of using `div.div.text` to extract the date, you can make use of the `span` tag that contains the date, like this:

```
review_date = div.span.next_element.strip()
```

The expression you use to extract the ratings will raise another error.

The "i-stars i-stars--regular-1 rating-large" applies for 1-star rating. So a 4-star rating would have a `div` with `class="i-stars i-stars--regular-4 rating-large"`, and so on.

So, you can make use of regex to filter the `div` containing the rating:

```
review_stars = div.find('div', {'class': re.compile(r'i-stars')}).img['alt']
```

Putting those two parts together, the two lines that need to be changed in your `reviews_info` function are:

```
review_date = div.span.next_element.strip()
review_stars = div.find('div', {'class': re.compile(r'i-stars')}).img['alt']
```

Make those changes and you should be good to go.

**Extra info:**

The reason I didn't use `div.span.text.strip()` to extract the text is that if the review was updated after its posting, the `span` tag contained that detail, too. And using `span.text` extracted that information, as well. Therefore, I chose `next_element`.

**Disclaimer:** I tested it on the third page alone, and it worked for me. I'm not sure if other pages will work without any issues.